# Migrating work items over with different ref names. Is there a way to change a field ref name for a work item type or set up a custom ref name?

Tags: azure, azure-devops, tfs-workitem, workitem, azure-devops-migration-tools

I am trying to migrate work items from a TFS server to Azure DevOps cloud using the VSTS Sync Migrator(https://nkdagility.github.io/azure-devops-migration-tools). I have most of the items migrating properly but I noticed that the descriptions were not coming over. After some investigating I see the the original TFS server has the "Description" field with a ref name "Common.DescriptionHtml". The default field for "Description" in ADO cloud is set to "System.Description". I assume that is why they are not syncing.  (see attached image: top is ADO cloud and bottom it original TFS server)

Is there a way to modify/change the field reference name in ADO cloud to be "Common.DescriptionHtml". If not then can I create a new field and customize its field reference name to be "Common.DescriptionHtml" so I can match it up with the original in the TFS server.

If the above is not possible, if I change the ref type for the "Description" field in the original TFS server will it corrupt or effect the original data on that TFS server for the "Description" field?
Yes, I am very new to this.

[image]

Comment: Did you look at the tool's documentation and ask a question on the GitHub project's issues page?

Comment: I did. Just wondering here if I could change or update the fields reference.

Answer (score 1):

You can remap fields using the VSTS Sync Migrator by configuring a **FieldtoFieldMapConfig** field map within your migration configuration json file.

In your case, it would look something like this:

```
{
    "$type": "FieldtoFieldMapConfig",
    "WorkItemTypeName": "*",
    "sourceField": "Common.DescriptionHtml",
    "targetField": "System.Description",
    "defaultValue": null
}
```

They have more examples of the FieldMaps available within their documentation here:

- https://nkdagility.github.io/azure-devops-migration-tools/getting-started.html

Answer (score 0):

We recommend that you use [migration guide and tool](https://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/services/devops/migrate/) to migrate data from Azure DevOps Server to Azure DevOps Services.

The data migration tool for Azure DevOps supports the two latest releases of Azure DevOps Server at a given time. Releases include updates and major releases. Currently the following versions of Azure DevOps Server are supported for import:

- Azure DevOps Server 2020
- Azure DevOps Server 2019.1.1

Depending on the screenshot you shared, it seems that you are using TFS2018, please refer to this doc [Upgrade your deployment to the latest version of Azure DevOps Server](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/server/upgrade/get-started?view=azure-devops-2020) to update your TFS version and then refer to this [doc to migrate data from Azure DevOps Server to Azure DevOps Services](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/migrate/migration-overview?view=azure-devops).

**Update1**

We cannot change or update the fields reference, in the TFS2019 and latest version, the field reference has been renamed to the `System.Description`, check the pic below. We need to update the TFS version and then migrate data from Azure DevOps Server to Azure DevOps Service. We recommend that you follow this [GitHub ticket](https://github.com/nkdAgility/azure-devops-migration-tools/issues/841) for more details.

[image]

Comment: The manager in charge of the original TFS server does not want to modify or update it so that is why I am going down this path.

Comment: Hi @ErnieAndBert, We cannot change or update the fields reference in the Azure DevOps Server or Azure DevOps Service, I have updated the answer, please check the update1